# "Msa AppId already in use" and creating a new AppId every time is not the solution

Tags: botframework

"Msa AppId already in use" and creating a new AppId every time is not the solution. I will loose all the channel added to my bot and need to reconfigure it with new AppId. Is there any other way around to make it work with existing appId?

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit more, wht are you getting "Msa AppId already in use"?

Comment: Why you need a new AppID?

Comment: @JasonSowers I used an app id for bot and then next day all my codes were gone. Since that app id and password i had saved i used it again. But its not accepting it. When i am trying to add new template with existing app id it shows error as Msa App Id already in use. Which i do not find it anywhere in Azure portal getting used.

Comment: @EzequielJadib Even i dont want a new app id. I want to reuse the existing one, But it always shows "Msa App Id is in Use" error message and doesn't let me add the bot template.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have a bot associated with the appid.  Please go to https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=[YourBotId] and delete the bot.  You should then be able to use that same appid with a different bot. One appid can only be assigned to one bot at a time.